# Equation of motion with non-linear drag

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics

Consider a particle of mass $m$ and electric charge $q$, initially at rest (zero
velocity, $v(0) = 0$), placed in a unidirectional potential $ψ(x) = −E_0qx \hspace{0.05in} \text{sin}(ωt)$. Assume that the particle experiences a spatially uniform electric force given by (for this one-dimensional system) as $F_E = −\frac{∂ψ}{∂x}$, and a nonlinear drag force in the from $F_D = δv^3$.

$(i)$ Use Newton’s second law to write the equation of motion for the particle’s velocity.

I have done the following

$F=ma=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= F_D - F_E = -\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} -\delta v^3 $

$m\frac{dv}{dt}=+E_0q \hspace{0.05in} \text{sin}(ωt) -\delta v^3$

I do not know how to proceed further to set up an integration that will yield a differential equation. I have tried doing this so far:

$\int \frac{m}{E_0q \hspace{0.05in} \text{sin}(ωt) -\delta v^3} dv = \int 1 \cdot dt$

Since velocity is a function of time (and vice versa), I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Is it demanded that you find a symbolic solution or symbolic insights for this equation? Does the $δ$ hint towards  perturbation approach?

Comment: Yes, later in the question it asks to take t˜= ωt and ˜v = v/v0 (with v0 to be determined) as the normalized, dimensionless, time, and velocity which will be substituted into the equation of motion to find v0, so that there remains only one dimensionless group and it is the coefficient of ˜v^3. Then, the obtained dimensionless equation of motion for ˜v(t) will be solved using a regular first-order perturbation method:

Comment: However, there is no reference to a symbolic solution

Comment: Then you should not try too hard in the direction you presented. The equation is not separable and the integrand of the left side is a function in $v$ and $t$, so the substitution of $t$ by $v$ is problematic, you would need to write $t=t(v)$ using an inverse function to $v(t)$. So after scale change you have $v'=\sin(t)-δv^3$? Next set $v=-\cos t+δw$ and determine the equation in the lowest remaining degree of $δ$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann
How did you arrive at the result $v′=sin(t)−δv^3$ and know to choose $v=−cost+δw$ as an acceptable substitution?

Comment: I just left out the tilde from the transformed variables for convenience. You get the first approximation by setting $δ=0$. Correctly integrated with the initial condition this should have been $v=(1-\cos t)+δw$. The perturbation is not singular, thus the perturbation expansion is a power series in $δ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
m\frac{dv}{dt}=+E_0q \hspace{0.05in} \sin(ωt) -\delta v^3
$$
is correct. Setting $\tilde t=ωt$, $v=v_0\tilde v$ results in
$$
mωv_0\frac{d\tilde v}{d\tilde t}=+E_0q \hspace{0.05in} \sin(\tilde t) -\delta v_0^3\tilde v^3
$$
Now selecting $v_0$ so that $mωv_0=E_0q$. Dividing be this factor and combining the remaining constants in a new constant $\tilde δ$ gives the normalized equation
$$
\frac{d\tilde v}{d\tilde t}=\sin(\tilde t) -\tilde \delta \tilde v^3.
$$

---

Drop the tildes for shortness. The solution for $\delta=0$ is $v=1-\cos t$. The perturbation for $δ\approx 0$ is regular, thus the solutions will also vary by terms of size $δ$. Set $v=(1-\cos t)+δw$, then
$$
\frac{dw}{dt}=-(1-\cos t)^3+O(δ)\implies w(t)=-t+3\sin t-\frac32(t+\sin t\cos t)+\sin t-\frac13\sin^3 t
$$
This is valid as long as $|δt|\ll 1$.